# Jquery hover add class and remove class on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have the following code of html

```
<div class="hover-block service-block">
                    <div class="hover-block-text">
                        <a href="#"><span class="displace">Haircut</span></a>
                        <h2>$40 <span>/</span> Haircut</h2>

                        <span class="icon">7</span>

                        <p>Our Best of Boston-winning haircut comes with a shampoo and conditioning treatment, neck shave, and complimentary beverage.</p>
                    </div><!-- /hover-block-text -->

                    <div class="hover-block-overlay">
                        <a href="http://example.com/con"><img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="Haircut" title="Haircut"></a>
                    </div><!-- /hover-block-overlay -->
                </div>
```

And i want on hover of the div with class `hover-block` the closest dive with class `hover-block-overlay` to add another class which is called `active-overlay`

The css of `active-overlay` is the following

```
.active-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
}
```

And what i've tried till now is this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $(function() {
          $('.hover-block').hover(function(){
          $(this).closest('div.hover-block-overlay').addClass('active-overlay');
          console.log("done");
      }, function(){

      });
  });
});
```

So when i hover on the div it prints `done` but the class is not changed!
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$(this).closest('div.hover-block-overlay').addClass('active-overlay');
```

to

```
$(this).find('div.hover-block-overlay').addClass('active-overlay');
```

Comment: Why you `$(function() {...}` in `document.ready` listener? Maybe this is unnecessary